Jaspersoft help - copying subreport jrxml files
using Jaspersoft Studio 7.9.0
The main issue is trying to copy an existing subreport in the repository folder under the main report.
Let’s say there’s a folder called “Portfolio Report”
Under it is a main.jrxml, which has a sub-report named (for lack of anything better) “SubRep”.
I want to make some major revisions to SubRep, so I figure making a copy of it and calling it SubRep2.jrxml and making changes to it, then in Main.jrxml, using the sub-report properties expression point to “repo:SubRep2.jrxml” instead of “repo:SubRep.jrxml”. this way I still have the original SubRep which I can roll back to. Minor changes I have no issue with modifying the active sub-report, but big changes, I like to version-archive the older sub-report in the folder.
I tried opening the SubRep, then doing a Save As and calling it SubRep2. The only problem is it doesn’t show up in the Repository Explorer (even after publishing it to the server). But it’s there because if I try to create a new XML file in the folder with the name SubRep2, it says that the ID is in use – even though it’s not visible (even after doing a refresh on the folder).
I’ve tried exporting/importing and copy/paste. There is nothing that I’ve tried that will make the new sub-report visible in the repository explorer.
What am I missing here?
Thanks

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
